# What is the advantage of using a immutable data structure in a map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am in the second chapter of the Programming Clojure book, and I came across this paragraph -

> Because Clojure data structures are immutable and implement hashCode
> correctly, any Clojure data structure can be a key in a map.

I cannot understand how the feature mentioned in the above quote would be advantageous.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand this using an example or point me to the right resources.

Answer (score 6):

This can be useful when forming a data structure that has *composite keys* i.e. keys that consist of more than one piece of information.

As a simple example, say we have a graph with vertices `:a` `:b` and `:c` and we wish to have a data structure which enables lookup of the cost metric associated with any edge. We can use a Clojure map where each key is a set:

```clj
(def cost {#{:a :b} 5
           #{:b :c} 6
           #{:c :a} 2})
```

We can now look up the cost associated with any edge:

```clj
(get cost #{:c :b})  ; => 6
```

Comment: Agreed, although I think using a map as key would be much more common than a set. Many clojure data types are defined as simple maps, such as `{:first-name "Steffan" :last-name "Westcott"}`, and it's natural to want a map keyed by such an object to look up other data related to it.

Answer (score 4):

In order to answer your question there are two things we need to discuss:

1. Hash Tables
2. Value vs Reference

In a hash table (and I'm grossly oversimplifying here) you take a "key" and you run it through a hashing function that converts that key in a unique* identifier that is then associated with an address in memory which holds a particular "value". This is the underlying abstraction for higher-level associative data structures like Clojure maps or Python dictionaries: you give me the key, I hash it, look up the address, give you back the thing.

In order for this scheme to work, the same key has to always hash to the same value for some definition of "same", otherwise you couldn't get the thing back out of the data structure.

In Java (and many other languages) the definition of "same" boils down to reference:

```java
public class Foo {
  int x = 5;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo myObj = new Foo();
    Foo myOtherObj = new Foo();
    myObj == myOtherObj; // false
    myObj.x = 6;
    myObj == myObj; // true
  }
}
```

Even though `myObj` and `myOtherObj` both hold the value 5 at the point of comparison, they are not equal *according to the rules of Java*, because they are different references. That last comparison, which looks non-sensical if you've never worked in a different model, highlights the problem: when we create `myObj` it has a value of 5, but at one point in time it has a value of 6. Is it still the same? Again, Java says yes.

And when we get to hashing something that is a potential key for a hash table that distinction matters: how do we maintain a consistent thing to feed the hash function? Is it the *value* (`x`) the container holds or the container (`Foo instance`)?

Python takes an interesting approach here:

```python
ls = [1, 2] # list
tp = (1, 2) # tuple
st = set()  # empty set

st.add(tp) # fine
st.add((1, 2)) # still only has 1 element, (1, 2) == (1, 2)
st.add(ls) # Error: unhashable type list!
```

In Python, you can't use mutable objects as set members or dictionary keys, because they are saying "the *meaning* of this thing changes" so it is unsuitable for a hashed key. But you can use any *immutable* type as a hash key (even an immutable container). Note that `(1, 2) == (1, 2)`, unlike in Java where two containers holding the same values are still compared on reference. Python compares mutable types by reference, but immutable types by *value*.

But in Clojure, *everything*** is immutable. *Everything* can be used as a hash key, because everything has a consistent value through time that can be fed to the hash function:

```clojure
(def x [1 2])

(def y { x 5 })

(get y x)     ; 5
(get y [1 2]) ; 5
```

When we lookup the vector bound to x in the map bound to y we get 5, since vectors are immutable we don't have to worry about identity. We don't have to pass around a reference like we do in Java, we can just create the value and use it as a lookup key.

* They're not *entirely* unique, per the pigeonhole principle unless the hashed output is at least as large as the input you will have collisions where two keys hash to the same values. But for our purposes here, they're unique.

** Not quite *everything*, but close enough.

Answer (score 0):

For its own data structures Clojure [uses hasheq](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#_clojure_collection_hashes) to create the hash of an object. The behaviour is consistent with `=`, which means that, for example, the list `'(1 2 3)` is equal to the vector `[1 2 3]`.

All Clojure data structures implement [`IHashEq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IHashEq.java) which means they have a `hasheq` function. If we compare the implementation of `hasheq` for the [`PersistentList`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java#L16) and [`APersistentVector`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentVector.java#L18) we see they both extend [`ASeq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ASeq.java) and have the same implementation of the [`hasheq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ASeq.java#L82) function, and when when getting to primitive types return a consistent value for the same values using a hashing algorithm called `Murmur3`.

If you look at the implementation of `hasheq` for longs we see `hashLong` is used of the [`Murmur3` class](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Murmur3.java) and we get consistent hash code values:

```clj
user=> (clojure.lang.Murmur3/hashLong 123)
823512154
user=> (clojure.lang.Murmur3/hashLong 123)
823512154
```

Similar for other primitive types.

Note that Java's `hashcode` function has similar behaviour for two types of ordered lists:

```
user=> (.hashCode (java.util.ArrayList. [1 2 3]))
30817

user=> (.hashCode (java.util.LinkedList. [1 2 3]))
30817
```

So an instance of ArrayList and LinkedList have the same hashcode as long as they have the same contents.

But a standard Java array returns different hashcodes not based on its contents, but specific to the instance:

```clj
user=> (.hashCode (to-array [1 2 3]))
1736458419
user=> (.hashCode (to-array [1 2 3]))
739210872
```

so two instances of similar arrays are not equal:

```clj
user=> (= (to-array [1 2 3]) (to-array [1 2 3]))
false
```

Now, why is this relevant when using Clojure data structures as keys in a map?

If we create a map with a vector or list as the key, we can look up this value:

```clj
user=> (def m {[1 2 3] :foo})
#'user/m
user=> (get m [1 2 3])
:foo
user=> (m [1 2 3])
:foo
```

also when using another data structure that is equal (`=`):

```clj
user=> (m '(1 2 3))
:foo
```

This is not possible with Java arrays that have an implementation for their hash codes that is based on the instance, not on the content:

```clj
user=> (def m {(to-array [1 2 3]) :foo})
#'user/m
user=> (m (to-array [1 2 3]))
nil
```

When using Clojure most things are coded using its data structures and it's advantageous that the lookups work based on the content of the data structure (`(get-in {[1 2] {#{2 3} :foo}} ['(1 2) #{3 2}]) ;; => :foo`).

Answer (score 0):

Input

```clj
(def my-cat "meaw")
(def my-dog "baw")
(def my-pets {my-cat "Luna"
              my-dog "Lucky"})
```

Output

```clj
(get my-pets my-cat) ;=> "Luna"
(:key my-pets my-cat) ;=> "meaw"
(get my-pets "baw") ;=> "Lucky"
(get my-pets "meaw") ;=> "Luna"
```